# Fit data with linear combinations of Cos and Sin

Tags: fitting, fourier-analysis

Recall that if $f$ is a piecewise continuous function on the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$, then the Fourier series of $f$ is

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a_n \cos(nx) + b_n \sin(nx)).$$

See for example, [this page](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Early%20Vectors/upfiles/FourierSeriesEV.pdf).

Suppose that I have the following *discrete* data stored in the List called `list`:

```
list = {{-6.28319,27.},
{-6.18319,29.9378},
{-6.08319,31.4545},
{-5.98319,31.4815},
{-5.88319,30.054},
{-5.78319,27.3079},
{-5.68319,23.4676},
{-5.58319,18.8269},
{-5.48319,13.7254},
{-5.38319,8.52035},
{-5.28319,3.5588},
{-5.18319,-0.849714},
{-5.08319,-4.45626},
{-4.98319,-7.09014},
{-4.88319,-8.66947},
{-4.78319,-9.20395},
{-4.68319,-8.78975},
{-4.58319,-7.59713},
{-4.48319,-5.85203},
{-4.38319,-3.81336},
{-4.28319,-1.7481},
{-4.18319,0.0934504},
{-4.08319,1.5002},
{-3.98319,2.31839},
{-3.88319,2.46391},
{-3.78319,1.92767},
{-3.68319,0.77379},
{-3.58319,-0.86928},
{-3.48319,-2.82358},
{-3.38319,-4.88107},
{-3.28319,-6.82563},
{-3.18319,-8.45569},
{-3.08319,-9.60509},
{-2.98319,-10.1604},
{-2.88319,-10.0728},
{-2.78319,-9.36378},
{-2.68319,-8.12337},
{-2.58319,-6.50193},
{-2.48319,-4.69555},
{-2.38319,-2.92666},
{-2.28319,-1.42171},
{-2.18319,-0.387886},
{-2.08319,0.00884309},
{-1.98319,-0.337699},
{-1.88319,-1.46055},
{-1.78319,-3.31281},
{-1.68319,-5.76826},
{-1.58319,-8.62934},
{-1.48319,-11.6421},
{-1.38319,-14.5166},
{-1.28319,-16.9518},
{-1.18319,-18.6617},
{-1.08319,-19.401},
{-0.983185,-18.9886},
{-0.883185,-17.3258},
{-0.783185,-14.4076},
{-0.683185,-10.327},
{-0.583185,-5.27092},
{-0.483185,0.492234},
{-0.383185,6.63133},
{-0.283185,12.7772},
{-0.183185,18.5507},
{-0.0831853,23.5918},
{0.0168147,27.5873},
{0.116815,30.2954},
{0.216815,31.5636},
{0.316815,31.3407},
{0.416815,29.6794},
{0.516815,26.7315},
{0.616815,22.7344},
{0.716815,17.9917},
{0.816815,12.8477},
{0.916815,7.66002},
{1.01681,2.7712},
{1.11681,-1.51793},
{1.21681,-4.97054},
{1.31681,-7.43032},
{1.41681,-8.83083},
{1.51681,-9.19685},
{1.61681,-8.63808},
{1.71681,-7.33557},
{1.81681,-5.52246},
{1.91681,-3.4608},
{2.01681,-1.41646},
{2.11681,0.365385},
{2.21681,1.68215},
{2.31681,2.3911},
{2.41681,2.42056},
{2.51681,1.77408},
{2.61681,0.527401},
{2.71681,-1.18153},
{2.81681,-3.16824},
{2.91681,-5.22173},
{3.01681,-7.12679},
{3.11681,-8.6864},
{3.21681,-9.74219},
{3.31681,-10.1909},
{3.41681,-9.99543},
{3.51681,-9.18896},
{3.61681,-7.87251},
{3.71681,-6.20529},
{3.81681,-4.38926},
{3.91681,-2.64914},
{4.01681,-1.20978},
{4.11681,-0.272896},
{4.21681,0.00442148},
{4.31681,-0.472474},
{4.41681,-1.72346},
{4.51681,-3.68806},
{4.61681,-6.22729},
{4.71681,-9.13288},
{4.81681,-12.1433},
{4.91681,-14.9649},
{5.01681,-17.2974},
{5.11681,-18.8597},
{5.21681,-19.416},
{5.31681,-18.7978},
{5.41681,-16.9216},
{5.51681,-13.7988},
{5.61681,-9.53872},
{5.71681,-4.34296},
{5.81681,1.50794},
{5.91681,7.67462},
{6.01681,13.7843},
{6.11681,19.4588},
{6.21681,24.3444}};
```

Plotting `list` using `ListPlot`, I see:

```
ListPlot[list, PlotRange -> {-25, 35}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.015]]]
```

[image: ListPlot]

I know that I can use the [`Fit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fit.html) function to "find a least-squares fit to a list of data as a linear combination of the functions *funs* of variables *vars*."  However, it seems that I can only have a ***single*** coefficient.  For example, in the following code, I do three different types of fits:

1. In `cosfit`, I fit `list` to `Cos[n*x]` functions: `cosfit = Fit[list, Table[Cos[n*x], {n, 0, end}], x];`
2. In `sinfit`, I fit `list` to `Sin[n*x]` functions: `sinfit = Fit[list, Table[Sin[n*x], {n, 0, end}], x];`
3. In `cossinfit`, I fit `list` to `Cos[n*x] + Sin[n*x]` functions: `Fit[list, Table[Cos[n*x] + Sin[n*x], {n, 0, end}], x];`

However, in the resulting fits, each function has only a single coefficient.  For example, the fit of `list` to `Cos[n*x] + Sin[n*x]` (i.e., in `cossinfit`) becomes:

$$c_0(\cos[0x] + \sin[0x]) + c_1(\cos[1x] + \sin[1x]) + c_2(\cos[2x] + \sin[2x]) + \ldots,$$

rather than

$$a_0\cos[0x] + b_0\sin[0x] + a_1\cos[1x] + b_1\sin[1x] + a_2\cos[2x] + b_2\sin[2x] + \ldots.$$

**My question is,** in the following code, how do I fit to *both* $\cos$ *and* $\sin$ (with separate coefficients in front of each $\cos$ *or* $\sin$ term)?

```
Grid[
 Table[

  cosfit = Fit[list, Table[Cos[n*x], {n, 0, end}], x];
  sinfit = Fit[list, Table[Sin[n*x], {n, 0, end}], x];
  cossinfit = Fit[list, Table[Cos[n*x] + Sin[n*x], {n, 0, end}], x];
  {
   Show[{
     ListPlot[list, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.015]]],
     Plot[cosfit, {x, list[[1, 1]], list[[-1, 1]]}, PlotRange -> All, 
      PlotStyle -> Black]
     }, PlotRange -> {-25, 35}, ImageSize -> 350, 
    PlotLabel -> "Cos Fit: n = " <> "0.." <> ToString[end]],

   Show[{
     ListPlot[list, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.015]]],
     Plot[sinfit, {x, list[[1, 1]], list[[-1, 1]]}, PlotRange -> All, 
      PlotStyle -> Black]
     }, PlotRange -> {-25, 35}, ImageSize -> 350, 
    PlotLabel -> "Sin Fit: n = " <> "0.." <> ToString[end]],

   Show[{
     ListPlot[list, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.015]]],
     Plot[cossinfit, {x, list[[1, 1]], list[[-1, 1]]}, 
      PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Black]
     }, PlotRange -> {-25, 35}, ImageSize -> 350, 
    PlotLabel -> "Cos/Sin Fit: n = " <> "0.." <> ToString[end]]
   }

  , {end, {1, 2, 5, 20, 25, 30}}]
 ]
```

which gives this output:

[image: FitOutput]

Is using `Fit` the way to go, or should I use some other built-in Mathematica function?

(In actuality, `list` was generated by taking discrete points from the function:

```
9 Cos[x] + 9 Cos[2 x] + 9 Cos[3 x] + 6 Sin[x] + 6 Sin[2 x] + 6 Sin[3 x]
```

which I chose as a minimal working example.  But in general, I will not know the functional form of the data in `list`, since in general I will obtain `list` from (noisy) empirical measurements.)

Comment: It almost seems like I should be using `FourierSeries` or something like that.  But in general I don't know the functional form of the data in `list` since `list` is in general obtained empirically.

Comment: `Table[Cos[n x], {n, 0, 10}] ~Join~ Table[Sin[n x], {n, 1, 10)]`.  But why don't you use `Fourier` instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that one way to accomplish *separate* coefficients for $\cos$ and $\sin$ is to define something like:

```
bothfit = Fit[list, Flatten[Table[{Cos[n*x], Sin[n*x]}, {n, 0, end}]], x];
```

where I use `Flatten` to flatten out the `Table` before the `Fit`.  I get this result:

```
Grid[
 Table[

  bothfit = 
   Fit[list, Flatten[Table[{Cos[n*x], Sin[n*x]}, {n, 0, end}]], x];

  {
   Show[{
     ListPlot[list, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.015]]],
     Plot[bothfit, {x, list[[1, 1]], list[[-1, 1]]}, PlotRange -> All,
       PlotStyle -> Black]
     }, PlotRange -> {-25, 35}, ImageSize -> 350, 
    PlotLabel -> "Both Fit: n = " <> "0.." <> ToString[end]]
   }

  , {end, {1, 2, 3, 5, 20, 25, 30}}]
 ]
```

[image: Flatten]

which seems like the correct result.  For example, if I look at the fit with `end` having the value `30`, the resulting function is essentially the function from which the data was derived for the minimal working example in the original post:

```
output = 1.41844*10^-16 + 9. Cos[x] + 9. Cos[2 x] + 9. Cos[3 x] + 
 3.79959*10^-15 Cos[4 x] + 4.69366*10^-15 Cos[5 x] + 
 1.78808*10^-15 Cos[6 x] - 3.12918*10^-15 Cos[7 x] - 
 1.3411*10^-15 Cos[8 x] - 4.47042*10^-16 Cos[9 x] + 
 4.47052*10^-16 Cos[10 x] + 7.82362*10^-16 Cos[11 x] - 
 5.02962*10^-15 Cos[12 x] + 2.90611*10^-15 Cos[13 x] - 
 3.12978*10^-15 Cos[14 x] + 4.69489*10^-15 Cos[15 x] + 
 1.56505*10^-15 Cos[16 x] + 2.23593*10^-15 Cos[17 x] + 
 6.70829*10^-16 Cos[18 x] - 8.94518*10^-16 Cos[19 x] + 
 3.91394*10^-15 Cos[20 x] + 5.36838*10^-15 Cos[21 x] - 
 1.5101*10^-15 Cos[22 x] + 6.26537*10^-15 Cos[23 x] - 
 3.58113*10^-15 Cos[24 x] + 2.23898*10^-15 Cos[25 x] - 
 2.24004*10^-15 Cos[26 x] + 2.68992*10^-15 Cos[27 x] - 
 1.79528*10^-15 Cos[28 x] + 4.49745*10^-16 Cos[29 x] - 
 1.80804*10^-15 Cos[30 x] + 6. Sin[x] + 6. Sin[2 x] + 6. Sin[3 x] + 
 1.34457*10^-15 Sin[4 x] - 2.24094*10^-15 Sin[5 x] - 
 3.13727*10^-15 Sin[6 x] + 1.56862*10^-15 Sin[7 x] + 
 2.24084*10^-16 Sin[8 x] + 7.17056*10^-15 Sin[9 x] - 
 2.24075*10^-15 Sin[10 x] + 8.96275*10^-16 Sin[11 x] + 
 2.68874*10^-15 Sin[12 x] + 1.79243*10^-15 Sin[13 x] - 
 1.79236*10^-15 Sin[14 x] - 8.06524*10^-15 Sin[15 x] - 
 3.13631*10^-15 Sin[16 x] + 4.48015*10^-16 Sin[17 x] - 
 8.95963*10^-16 Sin[18 x] + 2.23971*10^-15 Sin[19 x] + 
 8.95787*10^-16 Sin[20 x] - 2.01526*10^-15 Sin[21 x] - 
 1.56717*10^-15 Sin[22 x] + 6.7151*10^-16 Sin[23 x] - 
 2.23779*10^-16 Sin[24 x] - 3.57924*10^-15 Sin[25 x] + 
 3.35395*10^-15 Sin[26 x] + 2.23441*10^-15 Sin[27 x] + 
 4.46389*10^-16 Sin[28 x] + 1.78194*10^-15 Sin[29 x] + 
 2.21658*10^-15 Sin[30 x];

Chop[output]
```

> `9. Cos[x] + 9. Cos[2 x] + 9. Cos[3 x] + 6. Sin[x] + 6. Sin[2 x] + 6. Sin[3 x]`

But this approach may not be the best way to accomplish the fit.