# error in output fitting parameter

Tags: fitting

> I have the following discrete data (6001 data points) stored in the external file called **analysis**:
>   the format of data set as:

```
-0.32026    -0.00185
-0.32016    0.00488
-0.32005    0.01161
-0.31994    0.01834
-0.31983    0.02507
-0.31973    0.0318
-0.31962    0.03853
-0.31951    0.04526
-0.31941    0.05199
```

> what I want is to fit the data by Fourier series, and get fitting parameters $C_n$ (n>20)
>
> $\qquad y=\sum_n c_n \cos(nk)$，
>
> code likes the following:

```
list = Import["C:\Users\mxguan\Desktop\analysis.txt", "Table"]

bothfit = Fit[list, Flatten[Table[{Cos[n*x], Sin[n*x]}, {n, 0, end}]], x];

Grid[
Table[
bothfit = 
Fit[list, Flatten[Table[{Cos[n*x], Sin[n*x]}, {n, 0, end}]], x];

{
Show[{
ListPlot[list, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thickness[0.015]]],

Plot[bothfit, {x, list[[1, 1]], list[[-1, 1]]}, 
PlotRange -> All,PlotStyle -> Black]}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, 
ImageSize -> 350, PlotLabel -> 
"Both Fit: n = " <> "0.." <> ToString[end]]
}
, {end, {70}}]
]
```

> however,during the calculation,there are some error raiesd:

```
Table::iterb: Iterator {n,0,end} does not have appropriate bounds.

General::stop: Further output of Table::iterb will be suppressed during this calculation.

Fit::fitm: Unable to solve for the fit parameters; the design matrix is nonrectangular, non-numerical, or could not be inverted.
```

> The result is that only fitting curve are plot, but I can not find the fitting parameter,is there any fault in a input?

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `end` supposed to be?

Comment: @J.M.  Actually I'm a new learner for Mathematica and the code is based on the former question.  [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43391/fit-data-with-linear-combinations-of-cos-and-sin) . I thank `end` is the maximum value of series number `n`.

Comment: Since you didn't specify a value of `end`, you're getting these errors.

Comment: @J.M I think **end** have been set as **70** in the above example. Do you have any idea how can I output the fitting parameters?

Comment: Then there should be an `end = 70;` line before the one for `bothfit`. On another note: the function seems to be odd, so why are you fitting with cosine instead of sine?

Comment: To be clear, the error message `Table::iterb: Iterator {n,0,end} does not have appropriate bounds.` is appearing precisely because `end` has not been defined. That's the reason (the main one) you can't get the fitting parameters.